# If all problems in NP are polynomially reducible to SAT (Cook & Levin) can one also assume that all to SAT polynomially reducible problems are in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

From Cook & Levin's theorem we know that all Problems in NP are polynomially reducible to SAT: $ \forall_{L\in NP}: L \leq_{p}SAT$.

Is the opposite also true? That is if we know that a language L is reducible to SAT in polynomial time, can it be also stated that it must be in NP?

$L \leq_{p}SAT \Rightarrow L \in NP$

I am struggling to understand if this holds true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. More generally, if $A \le_p B$ and $B \in \mathbf{NP}$, then $A \in \mathbf{NP}$. (Most intro theory textbooks include a proof of this result.)

In fact, one way of defining what the class $\mathbf{NP}$ is is as “the class of all decision problems that polynomial-time reduce to $SAT$.”

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true, and to get a feeling for why it is so, we can appreciate the fact that a reduction is just an algorithm (in this case, a poly-time algorithm) that transforms instances of one problem into instances of another.

So, given a string $x$, one way to check if $x \in L$ is to run the reduction to SAT (in polynomial time) on $x$ and check if the resulting formula is satisfiable (in non-deterministic polynomial time). This is clearly a non-deterministic poly-time algorithm to check membership in $L$; in other words, $L$ is in $NP$.